# Expending window to maximim and movement

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have trying to expend my window to maximum and them I am moving it .

But after I moved it , the window returns to it's original size .

Any idea how I can make it satay on it's maximum size ?

```
<Window x:Class="Monitor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Misc="clr-namespace:Monitor.Misc" 
        Title="Monitor" Icon="Icon.ico" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        MaxHeight="244" MinHeight="224"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        d:DesignHeight="244" d:DesignWidth="553">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set set the `MinWidth` and the `MinHeight` properties of the window to match the match the values of `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight`.